# php array combine 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

will be get 3 array $_POST array.

```
$_POST["name"]=> array (
    [0] => product_1
    [1] => product_2
    [2] => product_3
)


$_POST["content"]=> array (
    [0] => content_1
    [1] => content_2
    [2] => content_3
)


$_POST["price"]=> array (
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
)
```

I need to fetch it and add to mysql. So, I think that need to combine 3 array to one array.

so I need get this format? and how can I do? :

```
$array =>(
    [0] => (product_1,content_1,100)
    [1] => (product_2,content_2,200)
    [2] => (product_3,content_3,300)
)
```

I tried array_combine(), but that's just support two arrays

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or just want codes?

Comment: I tried array_combine(), but that's just support two arrays

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Then use simple `foreach`.

Comment: Or adapt your form so you get the desired result directly in `$_POST`...

Comment: There are no tuples in php. It would be extremely hard to get anything like `[0] => (product_1,content_1,100)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining array inside multidimensional array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948739/combining-array-inside-multidimensional-array-with-same-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple use `foreach`

```
$new_array=array(); //create new array 

foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$val){ //loop any one of post 

 $new_array[]=array($_POST['name'][$key],$_POST['content'][$key],$_POST['price'][$key]); //create new array with the help of $key

}
```