# How to convert a multidimensional array into a single line array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I convert a multidimensional array like the one below

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
                    [0]=001
                    [1]=002
                    [2]=003
                )
    [1] => Array(
                    [0]=America
                    [1]=Japan
                    [2]=South Korea
                )
    [2] => Array(
                    [0]=Washington DC
                    [1]=Tokyo
                    [2]=Seoul
                )
)
```

into a single line array like the one below?

```
Array(
    [0]=001,America,Washington DC
    [1]=002,Japan,Tokyo
    [2]=003,South Korea,Seoul
)
```

Comment: Lazy person's solution: `array_map(function ($v) { return implode(",",$v); }, $array);`

Comment: see `implode()` to convert into strings 2nd level arrays.

Comment: It was easy for coding too and it helps me a lot thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variadiac php5.6+ version:  (Offers the added benefits of not breaking on missing values and inserting `null` where values are missing.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87385074a13b8cb498c94f0c7ab66325cee8c22e))

```
var_export(array_map(function(){return implode(',',func_get_args());},...$text));
```

The non-variadic version:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4bba9b5b0e5d06f23c7701762473529cae845b0f))

```
foreach($text as $i=>$v){
    $result[]=implode(',',array_column($text,$i));
}
var_export($result);
```

Input:

```
$text = [
    ['001','002','003'],
    ['America','Japan','South Korea'],
    ['Washington DC','Tokyo','Seoul']
];
```

Output from either method:

```
array (
  0 => '001,America,Washington DC',
  1 => '002,Japan,Tokyo',
  2 => '003,South Korea,Seoul',
)
```

Nearly exact duplicate page: [Combining array inside multidimensional array with same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948739/combining-array-inside-multidimensional-array-with-same-key)

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple code to work around,

```
foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        $result[$key1][] = $value1;
    }
}
array_walk($result, function(&$item){
    $item = implode(',', $item);
});
```

Here is the working [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab055017df58d7c3418801b28e55aecd7ac651f0)

[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array